# How to determine the type of game object in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function attached to the `onClick()` event of a button and an image and I would like to change the behavior, depending on the element clicked:

```
void example(){
    if(this.gameObject is a Button){
        //do something
    }else if(this.gameObject is a Image){
        //do something else
    }
}
```

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Try `if (gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() == null)`

Comment: @Kay it doesn't work ,both game object (button and image) enter the if (gameObject.GetComponent<Button>() == null)

Comment: Oops it must be `!= null` . Further on it has to be the game object that contains the Button itself. If the button component ist attached to a child it won't be found this way. In that case `GetComponentInChildren` could be used but this has some drawbacks (performance, side-effects) and should be used carefully

Comment: another solution create enum with all necessary types and add enum parameter to class, so when you add your script to GO just choose right enum in inspector (or fill it on Start() func with getcomponent) and in your method just switch variable